# Getting query to hit index - search for prefix of string

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I am trying to get a query to hit an index.

The scenario is this:

> Given a string - find all rows where the column 'str' is a substring to that string

I have tried something like:

```
SELECT str FROM tbl WHERE 'fullstring' LIKE CONCAT(str, '%');
```

However - this does not hit the index I have created when examining the query with `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`.

In the worst case I can fix this problem by remodelling the database a bit, using nested sets - but I would really love to not have to go down that route.

Comment: Will you post the explain plan?

Answer (score 0):

It should be using index. If your MySQL optimizer is not choosing proper index then you can try with `FORCE KEY` try:

```
SELECT str FROM tbl FORCE KEY(index_name) WHERE 'fullstring' LIKE CONCAT(str, '%');
```